# How do I know if iprules are used?

Tags: iptables

I followed this:
[How to save rules of the iptables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables)

And created this "/etc/iptables.rules":

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Sun May 19 18:42:18 2013
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [429624:571594561]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [174081:16941855]
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 173.194.55.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A INPUT -s 206.111.0.0/16 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May 19 18:42:18 2013
```

How do I know this is being used?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo iptables -L -nv
```

will show the current iptables rules.

Comment: Does this show it is using rules correctly? http://pastebin.com/iWcEgN6X

Comment: Yes, it is correct.