# Where are iptables's rulesets stored on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, networking, firewall, iptables

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - iptables v1.4.12

**TLDR:**

Where are iptables's rulesets saved when invoking `iptables-save <ruleset-name>` ?

**Explanation**:

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/119393/216975) basic way of saving iptables's rules is invoking

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4
ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

and afterwards loading/restoring these rules in `/etc/network/interfaces` like:

```
iface eth0 inet static
        ....
        pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4
        pre-up ip6tables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v6
```

... or putting these into a shell script in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d`.

---

This can be simplified by installing the `iptables-persistent` package.

```
sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
inovoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
update-rc.d iptables-persistent defaults
```

---

Following some tutorials i tried to invoke `service iptables status` ( a non-existant/unknown command for the `iptables` version/package that comes pre-installed with 12.04 ) and found this interesting output:

```
Aborting iptables initd: unknown command(s): "status".                                                               
  ...                                                                                  
  save <ruleset>                                                                                                    
     save the current ruleset                                                                                       
  load <ruleset>                                                                                                    
     load a ruleset                                                                                                 
   ...                                                                                                   
Saved rulesets:                                                                                                     
  active, inactive                                                                                 
...
```

There seem to be two rulesets i can load (`active` and `inactive`) ...

.. but **where are these stored**?

I can't find their location as active/inactive are pretty bad search terms and `dpkg-query -L iptables` doesn't help either.

As i'm provisioning my servers with `puppet`/`chef` it would be nice to know wether there is some place i can put my rulesets and add a simple shell script to `/etc/networking/if-pre-up` to load these.

Then i could ommit the `iptables-persistent` package which ain't that flexible as it doesn't allow loading different rulesets.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iptables stores the rules in memory but the **ruleset** created by `iptables-save ruleset-name` can be found in the file

**/var/lib/iptables/ruleset-name**

These can be restored by invoking `iptables-restore <ruleset-name>`.

I can only confirm this for Ubuntu 12.04.03 LTS - maybe this location has changed in later versions of the iptables-package.

I think something like `/etc/iptables/rulesets.d` would have been a more logical place to store these.

The save-path is configured in `/etc/init.d/iptables` at line **27** and afterwards used by `initd_save()` which invokes `initd_counters()`.

```
libdir=/var/lib/iptables   

# ...

initd_counters () {                                                                                         
 if test "${enable_save_counters:-false}" = true; then                                                     
    echo -n " with counters"                                                                                
    $iptables_save -c > "$ruleset"                                                                          
  else                                                                                                      
    $iptables_save | sed '/^:/s@\[[0-9]\{1,\}:[0-9]\{1,\}\]@[0:0]@g' > "$ruleset"                           
  fi                                                                                                        
}        

initd_save () {                                                                                             
  rm -f $autosave                                                                                           
  ruleset="${libdir}/$@"                                                                                    
  echo -n "Saving iptables ruleset: save \"$@\""                                                            
  initd_counters                                                                                           
  echo "."                                                                                                  
}
```

Comment: #cat /etc/os-release
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="12.04.4 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.4 LTS)"
    VERSION_ID="12.04"
    # iptables-save ruleset.1
    Unknown arguments found on commandline

This does not appear to work

Comment: same issue here