# Routing traffic over p2p1 and tun0 correctly

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, routing

I have been trawling these questions and trying many different solutions to get this working, but I seem to have a problem with getting my routing set up correctly. I have a box installed in a network with no Internet access with the exception of OpenVPN to my server. Everything else is blocked leaving the LAN segment the box is on.

The box opens a connection to my VPN server, so now I have p2p1 and tun0. The setup for /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.56.211
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.56.251
    dns-nameservers 192.168.100.20 192.168.50.35
```

The OpenVPN connection comes up and connects as you would expect, allowing me to SSH into the box via the VPN from outside the LAN. The issue is that *all* outgoing data is trying to use the local gateway. I haven't been able to get any routing configuration so far to pass the following:

1. Local LAN via 192.168.56.251
2. Secondary LAN (192.168.50.x) via 192.168.56.251
3. VPN Server via 192.168.56.251
4. Internet via tun0 (OpenVPN interface)

I've tried using

```
up route add -net 1.2.3.4/32 gw 10.8.4.9
```

to configure at least one server to get a connection via the VPN, but still no joy. It's like nothing is routing correctly. At the very minimum I at least need to get apt-get working via the VPN and then getting my webserver to go via it as well. I an cope with it being limited like that, but ideally I just want to fix it so the routes are correct!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `eth1` is the device I want to be an available gateway on my LAN, and `ppp0` is the name of my VPN connection when it's active on that machine (connects via `eth0` but for deadswitch security we won't name it in the routing).

Setup your IPtables for NAT from the LAN to the VPN-connected gateway:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
```

Remember to [save your iptables](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables) and [activate IP forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent).