# Revert iptables

Tags: 16.04, iptables

I created the following temporary rule that I enable occasionally but I would like to remove it without the need of restarting the machine.

Can someone provide me the command?

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eno1 -p TCP -d 149.202.80.48/32 --dport 2020 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.167.147.211:2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that you save your existing rules before making your adjustment, and then restoring those rules once you're done using the special rule.

1. `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules`
2. `iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eno1 -p TCP -d 149.202.80.48/32 --dport 2020 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.167.147.211:2020`
3. Do your thing.
4. `iptables --flush`
5. `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`

This would be especially useful if you have other iptables rules (such as those from `fail2ban`, etc).

---

Another option is to save your iptables to a file as described above, except instead of manually flushing and restoring, you could set up `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/` to restore, and have `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` flush.  This way, you could just do something such as `ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0` to get back to where you started.

---

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/119393/13247) may be helpful.