# How can I start the IP Tables service

Tags: iptables

How do you start or stop IP Tables

```
service iptables status

Unit iptables.service could not be found.



systemctl start iptables

Failed to start iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not found.
```

I found this file But there's no Indication of a start function

```
/usr/sbin/iptables-apply
```

I ran **find / -name "*iptables*"** and got this

```
/usr/bin/iptables-xml
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend_iptables.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/__pycache__/backend_iptables.cpython-36.pyc
/usr/sbin/iptables-apply
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/iptables
/usr/share/iptables
/usr/share/iptables/iptables-rules
/usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt
/usr/share/ufw/iptables
/usr/share/doc/iptables
/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Linux/_iptables
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-extensions.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-restore.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-save.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/iptables-apply.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/iptables-xml.1.gz
/usr/share/mime/text/x-iptables.xml
/usr/local/share/doc/pgl/examples/iptables-custom-remove.sh
/usr/local/share/doc/pgl/examples/iptables-custom-insert.sh
/usr/local/var/lib/pgl/.pglcmd.iptables.remove.sh
/etc/rsyslog.d/my_iptables.conf
/sbin/iptables-restore
/sbin/iptables
/sbin/iptables-save
/var/log/iptables.log
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.list
```

So where exactly does it start?

Comment: Being rude towards others is a bad thing.  `iptables` isn't a service you 'stop'.  It's the underlying system firewall.  You can *remove* `iptables`, but its not a service you can 'stop'.  What's the actual issue you're having?

Comment: "so many people" out of any contextual reference frame is an exaggeration of truth.  As a professional linux adminstrator myself, I can confirm that `iptables` is just a program that allows you to see the rules in place for the underlying `netfilter` system.  `ufw` is another similar program.  The filtering is done at a non-service level so there is no `iptables` *service* that really loads up at boot - it's just 'omnipresent'.  The only thing that you could do is a boot script that either loads up rules or flushes out rules to get back to a 'default' empty ruleset state

Comment: This being said, the original statement of "`iptables` is not a service" remains valid here.

Comment: If you wish to discuss further, we can in chat.  *However*, `iptables` is just a front-end *interface* to the underlying `netfilter` rulesets loaded up in memory for use at the *kernel* layer.  There's no `iptables` or `netfilter` *program* you can start or stop.

Comment: RHEL/Fedora runs iptables as a service, Debian/Ubuntu does not. use `iptables-persistant` . See https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iptables` is part of the kernel / `netfilter`.  It's not a specific service or program that you can 'start' or 'stop'.  It's ever-present, the only thing of relevance is what rules are loaded into it at a given time.

That means that the `iptables` command you call is actually just a front-end that helps with understanding / reading / interpreting / configuring the underlying `netfilter` rules at the system/kernel level for that boot session.  There is no given 'program' you can start or stop to disable `iptables` - there's *commands* you can run which do this (such as `iptables -F` among others), but there's no specific service to start or stop.

---

In comments, you refer to "other people" saying that it is a service.  In many cases, this isn't actually a *service* per-se, it's just a service-executable script which handles loading / unloading `iptables` rulesets.

There may be *other distributions* that ship these types of service scripts that manipulate `iptables` - indeed, I myself have a service script on my computer that has a 'start' and 'stop' call which either loads `iptables` rules from a file, or correspondingly *clears out* all rules and sets things back to the system default of 'accept all'.  This is, however, *not* shipped in the Ubuntu repositories, it's a script I wrote (and for 'fragile code' reasons I am not willing to share this at this time).

Ubuntu doesn't provide such service scripts for `iptables`.  You would need to write your own.  Or, consider using `ufw` if you want something simpler to maintain that you *can* load with system utilities (though, these are also 'scripts' that more or less control whether the `ufw`-defined rulesets are enabled or not, and you're really supposed to use `ufw enable` / `ufw disable` instead of those service scripts).

Comment: those are Metasploit specific documentations, but I can't testify to whether their exploit documentation is valid or not for Ubuntu.  "Linux" exploits aren't necessarily always going to target *all* versions of Linux, and I am not an expert when it comes to the various README documentations about various Metasploit exploits,.