# How to use IPtables for load balancing in gateway

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, nat

I have 3 NICs. NIC1 and NIC2 are used for internet connections
an LAN is used for intranet connection.

I want to balance the load to ISPs using ip tables. As I am a noob, my crude attempt is given in the following code, obviously without success. This code was assembled by looking at many websites on the topic.

we would like to optimally use the incoming internet in LAN using Round-Robin method

or

Is it possible to split the two isps, i.e, for systems 1 to 5 (ISP1) and 5 to 10 (ISP2) using routing tables?

Hope someone out there will help me, which is very much appreciated.

```
set -x
IPT="/sbin/iptables"
NIC1="enp4s5f0"
NIC2="enp4s5f1"
LAN="ens2"
ISP1="192.168.9.33"
ISP2="192.168.10.33"

#***************
# reset iptables
#_______________
## reset the default policies in the filter table.
$IPT -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPT -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

## reset the default policies in the nat table.
$IPT -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

## reset the default policies in the mangle table.
$IPT -t mangle -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPT -t mangle -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

## flush all the rules in the filter and nat tables.
$IPT -F
$IPT -t nat -F
$IPT -t mangle -F

## erase all chains that's not default in filter and nat table.
$IPT -X
$IPT -t nat -X
$IPT -t mangle -X


#*********************
# enable IP forwarding
#_____________________
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward


#****************
# rules 
#________________
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
$IPT -A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 

$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP 
$IPT -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
$IPT -A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT 

$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i NIC1 -p tcp --dport 80\ 
            -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode\ 
            random --probability .33 -j  DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.1:1

$IPT -t nat -A PREROUTING -i NIC2 -p tcp --dport 80\ 
            -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode\ 
            random --probability .33 -j  DNAT --to-destination 10.1.1.1:2

$IPT -A FORWARD -i $NIC1 -o $LAN -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i $NIC2 -o $LAN -j ACCEPT


# ifconfig -a


#********************************
# allow certain hosts full access
#________________________________

allowHost() {
    $IPT -A FORWARD -i $LAN -s $1 -j ACCEPT 
}

allowHost 192.168.2.10
allowHost 192.168.2.11
allowHost 192.168.2.12
allowHost 192.168.2.13
allowHost 192.168.2.14
allowHost 192.168.2.15

####Extra
$IPT -A FORWARD -d 8.8.8.8 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 53 -j ACCEPT

#********************
# block anything else
#____________________
$IPT -A FORWARD -j LOG -m limit --limit 10/minute --limit-burst 1 --log-prefix "Blocked:"
$IPT -A FORWARD -j DROP

/sbin/modprobe ip_tables
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack
/sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
/sbin/modprobe ip_nat_ftp
/sbin/modprobe iptable_nat
```

[image: Network Topography]

Comment: Let me clarify a point here, are we talking of balancing the load to each of connected computers, i.e. sharing the in-bound data packets from the two ISPs?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, No we would like to optimally use the incoming internet in LAN using Round-Robin method.

Comment: This should have been stated in your question!

Comment: Please can you add an image of your network connection or a sketch. Look at this example: https://www.webair.com/community/simple-stateful-load-balancer-with-iptables-and-nat/

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, I have seen this website, but I am unable to understand the code. Is it possible to split the two isps, i.e, for systems 1 to 5 (ISP1) and 5 to 10 (ISP2) using routing tables.

Comment: Yes, that is very possible and now that you have stated your configuration clearly we can understand better.

Comment: @George Udosen We are waiting for your kind response.

Comment: please add an image of your network topology!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Network topology image added.

Comment: what version of ubuntu are we talking here?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: it can be done through marking packet using mangle table, and set routing policy based on marked packet.

Comment: @KhimanandaOli Kindly guide me

Answer (score 1):

#### WARNING: READ THROUGH FIRST BEFORE EXECUTING

#### DISCLAIMER: Untested

Prerequisites:

1. Install the iptables persistent package

   ```
   sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent
   ```
2. Backup your existing iptables rules:

   ```
   sudo iptables-save > ~/iptables-export
   ```

   - Restore:

     ```
     sudo iptables-restore < ~/iptables-export
     ```
3. Flush the former iptables rules:

   ```
   sudo iptables -F && sudo iptables -t nat -F && sudo iptables -t mangle -F && sudo iptables -X && sudo iptables -t nat -X && sudo iptables -t mangle -X
   ```

Steps:

1. Add a new "route table" using this command from your terminal to handle the packets from one of the NIC's:

   ```
   sudo bash -c 'echo "1 rt2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables'
   ```
2. Enable ipv4 forwarding

   ```
   sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   sudo sysctl -p
   ```
3. Add filter that allows "masquwerading"

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.90
   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.90


   sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens2 -j MASQUERADE
   sudo netfilter-persistent save
   sudo netfilter-persistent reload
   ```
4. Edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add the configuration for the
   second NIC, but ofcourse **make a copy of the old one**,

   `sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bkup`:

   ```
   iface enp4s5f1 inet static
       address <YOUR_NIC_ADD>/24
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       post-up ip route add 192.168.10.0/24 dev enp4s5f1 src 192.168.10.33 table rt2
       post-up ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp4s5f1 table rt2
       post-up ip rule add from 192.168.10.33/32 table rt2
       post-up ip rule add to 192.168.10.33/32 table rt2
   ```

   - Restart network manager:

     ```
     sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
     ```
5. Add iptable rules:

   ```
   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
    --every 5 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.26

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
    --every 4 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.27

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
    --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.28

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
    --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.29

   sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 --to-destination 192.168.2.30
   ```

=====================================

```
    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
     --every 5 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.21

    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
     --every 4 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.22

    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
     --every 3 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.23

    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth
     --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.24

    sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.25

    sudo netfilter-persistent save
    sudo netfilter-persistent reload
```

Source:

https://scalingo.com/articles/2018/04/20/iptables.html

https://www.webair.com/community/simple-stateful-load-balancer-with-iptables-and-nat/

http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html

https://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/Spanning_Multiple_DSLs

[How to save rules of the iptables?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables)

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-network-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-linux

Comment: `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 --to-destination 192.168.2.30`

needed to be changed to

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp4s5f0 -m state --state NEW -m statistic --mode nth  --every 1 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.2.30`

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.2.21 but ping www.google.com does not work.

Comment: I think connection POSTROUTING is not working.