# Installation of SQL server in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

I am beginner to ubuntu. Can anyone suggest me how to install .exe files in ubuntu machine or in particular, SQL server 2008 ?

Comment: To run .exe files [install wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-wine). About SQL server, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90858/can-i-run-sql-server-on-ubuntu)

Comment: From personal experience: it will be easier to either dump the data, edit the tables to fit into mysql and use mysql. If you want to use MSSQL stick with Windows. Or to use a MSSQL connector from Ubuntu and probe the Windows MSSQL Server for the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'Wine' for installing most of the .exe file. But you can't install mssql server 2008.But you can install mysql server instead.

To install MySQL you must install the Metapackage mysql-server. This can be done by searching for and installing in the Software Centre, or by running the following command-
        `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

But if you really want to install Microsoft SQL then you can install 2000 sp3 but not the 2008 as wine does not support mssql 2008 
You can check this link :
[Click here to go to wine website](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=11016)
and you can also check this for LAMP(linux apache, mysql,php) installation 
[Click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)