# sqlcmd not available after installing mssql-tools

Tags: server, apt, database, mssql

I'm trying to access sql server database so i need sqlcmd but after following microsoft docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-connect-and-query-sqlcmd). Running sqlcmd returns:

```
 sqlcmd: command not found
```

and I do have mssql-tools installed:

```
amir@amir-pc:~$ sudo apt-get install mssql-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mssql-tools is already the newest version (14.0.2.0-1).
```

What am i missing? Also i'm on 16.10 and i had no problem installing it on 16.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [the page you linked to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools#ubuntu):

> Optional Step: Create symlinks to 'SQLCMD' and 'BCP' under /usr/bin/.
>
> ```
> ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/sqlcmd 
> ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp-13.0.1.0 /usr/bin/bcp
> ```

Comment: The commands might not work as it is, I had to remove the version numbers from binary paths like so: `ln -sfn /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd /usr/bin/sqlcmd`

Answer (score 2):

1. Add the path either to *~/.bash_profile* or *~/.profile* if you don't have .bash_profile in your home directory.

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
   ```
2. Add the following path to your *~/.bashrc* file

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"
   ```
3. Don't forget to update the path configuration by issuing the following command in your terminal window:

   ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   ```