# sqlcmd not found. mssql-tools not found after installation

Tags: mssql

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870927/sqlcmd-not-available-after-installing-mssql-tools) which suggested me to create links. But turns out the mssql-tools is not found in /opt directory even though i had just installed it. What should i do to get sqlcmd working?

Comment: Please add your OS/Version

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: What is the content of your `/opt` directory? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/sqlcmd` and `ls -l /usr/bin/bcp`?

Comment: @StrabagISS_Krall The output for the cmds are /usr/bin/sqlcmd -> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd and /usr/bin/bcp -> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp