# How To Install Visual Studio, SQL Server On Ubuntu

Tags: photoshop

i'm a developer and i use Visual Studio, Sql Server , Photoshop, And Many Another Program For My Work.

Now For Some Reasons I Want Install Ubuntu And Use That Programs For My Work.

Now How Can I Install That Programs On Ubuntu , [ I Don't Want Use Similar Programs On Ubuntu ]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest you to stay with Windows, because it seems everything you are using is depend on Windows. You should wisely choose your tools, and making Ubuntu into something it's not is not a logical thing. Even if you do, it's not going to be as good experience as you had with windows.

If you insist, my suggestions are:

1. Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows
   Its the best thing you can do, you've got all your necessary stuff on your windows while you have your Ubuntu on same machine.
2. Use Virtualization
   Some of your applications are not suppose to work with GNU/Linux at all, you better install them on a virtual Windows machine so at the same time you have Ubuntu and your windows programs.
3. Use Wine
   Wine is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux

   Check [Wine applications database](https://appdb.winehq.org) to see if your desired applications are supported by wine if they are, you can use wine to run them on Ubuntu.
4. Combine Wine/Virtualization
   Some of applications are fine to run using wine, the others might have some problems, use wine and virtualization to get best result you can.

---

Useful questions:

[How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)
[How can I install Visual Studio?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio)
[Can I run SQL Server on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90858/can-i-run-sql-server-on-ubuntu)